# função explode não funcionar com 2 quebras de linha

Tags: php, html, quebras-de-linha

Eu tenho o seguinte problema, tenho um texto/string em estrofes, exemplo:

> t is a long established fact
>  that a reader will be distracted
>   by the readable content of a page
>  when looking at its layout.
>   
>  t is a long established fact
>  that a reader will be
>   distracted
>  by the readable content of a page
>  when looking at
>   its layout.
>  t is a long established fact
>  that a reader
>   will be distracted
>  by the readable content of a page
>  when
>   looking at its layout.

E preciso quebrar essa string e salvar como um array com cada posição, uma estrofe.
Eu consegui fazer isso com o `explode("<br/><br/>", $letra);`
Funciona tranquilo no `localhost`, mas na hora que vai pra hospedagem não funciona mais, fiz testes e só funciona com 1 <br/> com os 2 não funciona, e não sei o porquê.

Já tentei resolver com \n\n mas não funciona.O que faco?

Comment: Ja achei o problema eu estava utilizando  PHP_EOL que estava atrapalhando